# Can't log multiple items in Analytics Events E-commerce

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, e-commerce, analytics

I need to log items in carts but I can't figure out how to do that. In Swift it is not allowed to use append() function, so I tried to create a dictionary inside an array but with this method it does not work properly, I got an error in Firebase Debugview. Here is my codes: (Swift, iOS)

```
func logViewCart(items: [CartItem]){
  
    var itemList : [[String : Any]] = []
    
    for item in items{
        var itemParams : [String : Any] = [
            "item_id": item.id,
            "item_name": item.product?.name,
            "item_category": item.product.category,
            "price": item.price
        ]

        itemList.append(itemParams)
    }
    
    var itemTest : [String : Any] = [:]
    
    for i in itemList {
        itemTest[AnalyticsParameterItems] = [i]
    }

    
    Analytics.logEvent("view_cart", parameters: [
        "items": [itemTest]
    ])
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Instead of declaring a dictionary inside an array, declaring another array variable with [Any] type solve the problem.

```
var itemList : [Any] = []
    
    for item in items{
        let variantIndex = item.product?.attributes?[1].listValueLabel?.count ?? 1
        var itemParams : [String : Any] = [
            "item_id": item.itemID,
            "item_name": item.product?.name
        ]

        itemList.append(itemParams)
    }

    
    Analytics.logEvent("view_cart", parameters: [
        AnalyticsParameterItems: itemList
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

There's several ways for the error you are getting, you can start by typing the log message or the behaviour.

I'll go first for the basics on login an event, make sure you have this property set `-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled` on your scheme like so

[image]

With that should popUp like in 3~6 seconds on the debug viewer, then make sure you have the parameters right.